# How to ignore white space and comma when reading from a file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

I have a comma separated file and i need to extract third field from each line.File test.txt has following contents:

```
6,STRING TO DECIMAL WITHOUT DEFAULT,cast($src_fld as DECIMAL(15,2) $tgt_fld 
7,STRING TO INTERGER WITHOUT DEFAULT,cast($src_fld as integer) $tgt_fld                
10,DEFAULT NO RULE,'$default' $tgt_fld
```

> cat test.txt |  awk -F, '{print $3}'

if i write above command ,i get an incorrect output as :

```
> cast($src_fld as DECIMAL(15
> cast($src_fld as integer) $tgt_fld
> '$default' $tgt_fld
```

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve it.I need to write it in a loop so that further processing can be done later. Please note that each third field may contain white space and comma(,).

Comment: I don't understand. `awk` does loop over the file line by line?

Comment: I have edited my question with proper output now.

Comment: No you didn't. All the question shows is the output you get that you DON'T want, not the output you do want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you say, the first two fields don't contain a comma, you can use `cut` with a comma as field delimiter:

```
$ cut -d ',' -f 3- test.txt 
cast($src_fld as DECIMAL(15,2) $tgt_fld 
cast($src_fld as integer) $tgt_fld                
'$default' $tgt_fld
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you also tell me how do i use this command inside a for loop. Because i need to process third field later after extracting it. If i write it as ***for i in `cut -d ',' -f 3-  test.txt`;do echo $i;done;***, it does not provide proper output.

Comment: @user1768029 You could do `while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done < <(cut -d ',' -f 3- test.txt)` to loop over it, but depending on what you want to do, it might not be ideal.

Comment: @user1768029, [don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @user1768029, don't use shell loops to manipulate text (e.g. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

Not a general solution but works for your format

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) $3 = $3 FS $i} {print $3}' badcsv

cast($src_fld as DECIMAL(15,2) $tgt_fld
cast($src_fld as integer) $tgt_fld
'$default' $tgt_fld
```

**Explanation** You're printing the part of the text after 2nd field based on FS=",".  The script appends the rest of the fields on $3 before printing.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a comma within the first two fields, your task is impossible.

```
1,second,field,with,commas,third,field,with,commas
```

You have no way of knowing where the 2nd field ends and the 3rd field begins.

You really have to use actual CSV syntax, and parse the file with a CSV parser.

```
1,"second,field,with,commas","third,field,with,commas"
```

---

If you can be certain that there are no commas in the first two fields, you can do:

```
sed 's/^[^,]\+,[^,]\+,//' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am sure that there will not be any comma in first two fields. Can you please explain me  how above sed command works? Can i extract only third field from the above command ?

Comment: It removes the first two comma-separated fields, leaving only the third. `[^,]\+` is one or more non-comma characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what the correct output is, just what it isn't, so this is a guess at what you might want but you should be able to figure out what you need from it if this isn't quite right:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    $0 = gensub(/([(][^()]+),([^()]+[)])/,"\\1"RS"\\2","g",$0)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        gsub(RS,FS,$i)
        print NR, NF, i, $i
    }
    print "----"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 3 1 6
1 3 2 STRING TO DECIMAL WITHOUT DEFAULT
1 3 3 cast($src_fld as DECIMAL(15,2) $tgt_fld
----
2 3 1 7
2 3 2 STRING TO INTERGER WITHOUT DEFAULT
2 3 3 cast($src_fld as integer) $tgt_fld
----
3 3 1 10
3 3 2 DEFAULT NO RULE
3 3 3 '$default' $tgt_fld
----
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks use match()+substr().

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a loop, you can use

```
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2 rest_of_line; do
   echo "Field 3: ${rest_of_line}" 
done < test.txt
```